# EC2 and Apache HTTPD no access via IP but via DNS name

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, httpd

I have some trouble with my EC2 instance. I have a normal Amazon Linux with the standard Apache HTTPD. My problem is that I can't access the HTTPD via IP address (e.g. http://123.123.123.123/), but when I'm using the DNS provided by Amazon everything works fine (e.g. ec2-123-123-123-123.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com).

Have anyone an ideas what could be wrong their?

Best regards, Johannes.

Answer (score 1):

On your instance, run `host ec2-123-123-123-123.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com` (your instance's public DNS hostname).  See that it does not, in fact, resolve to 123.123.123.123, but rather to an [RFC 1918 address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) (probably 10.x.x.x)?  Amazon uses [split-view DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-horizon_DNS), so the hostname resolves to the public IP outside the region/VPC, but resolves to the private IP inside.  Firewall rules based on security group memberships *only* work when access is via the private IP.

Comment: Hi Karen, thanks for your answer. You are right, the host command resolves to an private IP. But how can I fix my network setup? Sorry for my dumb question. But I assume, that there are millions of EC2 instances with a HTTPD server which I can assess via IP. What is the difference to my system? Regards.

Comment: Are you asking how you can access your instance's web server from your instance?  You can use the private IP (or private DNS name), or add the public IP to the security group ingress rules.

Comment: Hi Karen, I think there is a missunderstanding. My problem is, that I can't access the HTTPD server from the public internet via the public IP, but access via the DNS name is OK. The strange thing is, that the access to other port (e.g. Oracle DB port 1521) via IP works. Only the HTTPD server or port 80 makes trouble.